# How to change node display according to value of date field

Tags: display-suite, theming

I have a need to display a node differently once a date field ('subscription expiry') of the node has passed. This is for subscription-based content. Ideally I would like to be able to choose a different Display Suite view when the alter the display of the node when the subscription expiry date is before today.

I have looked at preprocess functions and at altering the node template but have yet to find an elegant solution. The number of fields is quite high: about 35 for the full view and about 15 for the limited view. I have created corresponding DS views but I would like to find how I can alter the view according to the value of the subscription expiry field.

My workaround is to use template_preprocess_field to hide each field I want to restrict, but this seems a bit long-winded.

Any suggestions would be most welcomed!